# MVVM pattern in WPF - How to go about Models I have no control about?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been getting my head into WPF the last few days, coming from a WinForms background, I just love the flexibility, especially in terms of binding.

However, I had a question after reading the following article on MVVM: http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx

How to go about Models I have no control over, I cannot add interfaces to it, etcetera, I can only use them as-is?

Looking at the article, one option for me is to just directly expose the Model in my ViewModel, but would this be a good way to go about it? I could also use the wrapping option, but how do I bubble changes to those bubbles back to the ViewModel if they don't have a INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Are there any other options that allow TwoWay-binding to these Models?

EDIT:
Consider the following classes as models I cannot modify, what are my options:

```
[DataContract]
public class NPCTypeData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;   

    [DataMember]
    public List<NameAlias> Emotions;
}

[DataContract]
public class NameAlias
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    [DataMember]
    public string Alias;
}
```

I don't really care about the code required to turn these into bindable classes, I just want one or more examples on where to start with nested dependencies like this.

Do I copy all data to a Model that does have bindable properties and just leave these for serialization, do I wrap them, or what?

Comment: If you don't have access to models, you can create a new ViewModel for each model and expose the properties you want, like a wrapper.

Comment: I had been thinking about that, but that's an awful lot of work and also "is it worth it?". How to go about collections of models within them (say a Customer object, which has a List of Order objects, which in turn can have even more references)? How to persist changes back to the original models and how to detect changes in the non-VM models?

Comment: That all depends... There's no definitive answer to your questions I'm afraid. You just should do what makes most sense in your current situation.

Comment: In my experience I always find there's some expressive property that I end up wanting to add to the model that I can't touch and I curse myself for not creating a wrapper viewmodel. Most (not all) of the time, it's worth it. It's better to spend ten minutes writing a wrapper now than spend 3 hours refactoring to include the wrapper type that you find you needed..

Comment: Very wise advise, would you have an example of how you usually approach this. The models I can't modify are pretty complex, nested dependencies, lists of other models, etc. I'm kinda at a loss on where to start wrapping them.

Comment: @Charleh I edited my post with an example of models I have (I have no control over them, they are as-is). How would you approach wrapping them and making them bindable?

Comment: @Charleh - You can of course combine the two: generate an INPC wrapper and write your own VMs that expose those wrapped Models as properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Henk, and would add that one option can be the "dynamic proxy class creation" which is what entity framework does. Basically: you have your POCO objects, and Entity framework can attach dynamically the necessary functionality to track the changes on model.

There's also an option to inherit from a class, and decorate the class with AOP attribute which generates all the necessary plumbing on the fly.

You can google for:

- `AOP INotifyPropertyChanged` - http://www.postsharp.net/
- `Automatic INotifyPropertyChanged using Dynamic Proxy` - http://jonas.follesoe.no/2009/12/23/automatic-inotifypropertychanged-using-dynamic-proxy/

When I had such problem, I basically used Henk solution, creating new classes and wrapping each property, using AutoMapper. Did it work & was it maintable? Yes, it worked, and it was maintable. Was it painful? **Yes**.

```
public class NPCTypeDataViewModel
{
    public string Name { 
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<NameAliasViewModel> Emotions {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public NPCTypeDataViewModel(NPCTypeData data){
        Name = data.Name;
        Emotions = data.Emotions.Select(x => new NameAliasViewModel(x))
                                .ToList();
    }

    public NPCTypeData GetModel(){
        var ntd = new NPCTypeData(){
            Name = Name,
            Emotions = Emotions.Select(emo => emo.GetModel())
                                .ToList()
        };

        return ntd;
    }
}

public class NameAliasViewModel 
{
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Alias {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public NameAliasViewModel(NameAlias alias){
        Name = alias.Name;
        Alias = alias.Alias;
    }

    public NameAlias GetModel(){
        return new NameAlias(){
            Name = Name,
            Alias = Alias
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: "Was it painful? Yes." This made me chuckle, at least you're honest, haha. I'll look at those links, thanks!

Comment: I edited my post with an example of models I have (I have no control over them, they are as-is). How would you approach wrapping them and making them bindable?